# Why do plugins in WordPress dashboard break on live server?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, wordpress-4.5.2

I developed a WordPress site (4.5.2) on my local server using the Brown theme, and everything in the dashboard looked fine. But when I migrated the site to the live server, the plugins in the dashboard looked broken, specifically the Visual Composer and Maintenance. When I used another theme, like Twenty-sixteen, the plugins looked fine. Is this an issue with the Brown theme? Or the live server?

Comment: If the issue disappears when changing themes then there is a conflict with the theme. If it was the server the problem should persist even after changing themes.

Comment: How did you migrate it? Could it be that some URLs are still pointing to localhost?

Comment: Try to shut down local server and then open a live site and open dev tools on chrome and go to console tab. See what the errors will be.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I contacted the theme developer, and he was able to fix it. The URL is lessergodsbooks.com. This is what he said was the problem: 
"The theme detects string "less" in your domain name and try to include "less" in CSS include syntax. I have [to] fix it and also apply this fix to the next update."